# Erro ao converter valor para JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Estou com um erro ao passar valor formatado para a `JTable`, se alguém puder ajudar, agradeço muito.

Esse erro só acontece quando eu formato o número, gostaria de saber como eu faço para corrigir isso.

Código:

```
    private void calcularButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    // valor < 3.000 = 0.12
    // valor >= 3.000 && valor <= 5.000  = 0.18
    // valor >= 9.000 && valor <= 30.000  = 0.22
    // valor >= 40.000 && valor <= 90.000  = 0.24
    // valor >= 100.000 && valor <= 150.000  = 0.27
    // valor >= 160.000 && valor <= 210.000  = 0.31
    // valor >= 300.000 && valor <= 500.000  = 0.32
    // valor >= 1.000.000 && valor <= 2.000.000  = 0.34

    String posicao = posicaoTextField.getText();
    String nome = nomeTextField.getText();
    float valor = Float.valueOf(valorTextField.getText());
    float valorVenda = 0;

    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) valoresTableView.getModel();

    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("R$ ###,###.00");  



    if (valor < 3000) {
        valorVenda = (float) (valor * 0.095);
        float valorTotalVenda = valor + valorVenda;
        System.out.println(nf.format(valorTotalVenda));
    }

    if (valor >= 3000 && valor <= 8000 ) {
        valorVenda = (float) (valor * 0.137);
        float valorTotalVenda = valor + valorVenda;
        System.out.println(nf.format(valorTotalVenda));
    }

    if (valor >= 9000 && valor <= 39999) {
        valorVenda = (float) (valor * 0.163);
        float valorTotalVenda = valor + valorVenda;
        System.out.println(nf.format(valorTotalVenda));
    }

    if (valor >= 40000 && valor <= 99999) {
        valorVenda = (float) (valor * 0.185);
        float valorTotalVenda = valor + valorVenda;
        System.out.println(nf.format(valorTotalVenda));
    }

    if (valor >= 100000 && valor <= 159999) {
        valorVenda = (float) (valor * 0.191);
        float valorTotalVenda = valor + valorVenda;
        System.out.println(nf.format(valorTotalVenda));
    }

    if (valor >= 160000 && valor <= 219999) {
        valorVenda = (float) (valor * 0.217);
        float valorTotalVenda = valor + valorVenda;
        System.out.println(nf.format(valorTotalVenda));
    }

    if (valor >= 300000 && valor <= 999999) {
        valorVenda = (float) (valor * 0.223);
        float valorTotalVenda = valor + valorVenda;
        float valorGanho = valorTotalVenda - valor;
        dtm.addRow(new Object[]{nome,
                                posicao,
                                df.format(valor).toString(),
                                df.format(valorTotalVenda),
                                df.format(valorGanho)});
    }

    if (valor >= 1000000 && valor <= 9999999) {
        valorVenda = (float) (valor * 0.239);
        float valorTotalVenda = valor + valorVenda;
        float valorGanho = valorTotalVenda - valor;
        dtm.addRow(new Object[]{nome,
                                posicao,
                                df.format(valor).toString(),
                                df.format(valorTotalVenda),
                                df.format(valorGanho)});
    }



}
```

E o erro que aparece é esse:

> ```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number
> at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(DecimalFormat.java:507)
> at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:157)
> at javax.swing.JTable$DoubleRenderer.setValue(JTable.java:5356)
> at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(DefaultTableCellRenderer.java:257)
> at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5723)
> at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(BasicTableUI.java:2114)
> at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(BasicTableUI.java:2016)
> at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(BasicTableUI.java:1812)
> at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
> at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:780)
> at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
> at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5210)
> at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:290)
> at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
> at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5158)
> at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4969)
> at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:831)
> at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
> at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
> at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
> at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
> at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
> at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
> at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
> ```

Comment: Você tá passando algum dado que o numberformat não é capaz de formatar, mas não deu pra identificar somente com este trecho, adicione um **[mcve]** do código para que seja possivel testar.

Comment: Se o valor for 8500, onde ele deveria cair?

Comment: Além disso, a lógica dos números descritos no comentário do código não bate com a lógica implementada no código abaixo.

Comment: Os comentários eram uma pequena base, tranquilo, e o valor de 8500 eu corrigi aqui:
`if (valor >= 4000 && valor <= 8999 ) {
            float valorVenda = (float) (valor * 0.098);
            float valorTotalVenda = valor + valorVenda;
            float valorGanho = valorTotalVenda - valor;
            dtm.addRow(new Object[]{nome,
                                    posicao,
                                    df.format(valor),
                                    df.format(valorTotalVenda),
                                    df.format(valorGanho)});
        }`

Comment: Esse código parece estar incompleto, o erro estoura no método setvalueAt, e esse código nem tem a ver com ele.

Comment: fiz um teste, se eu não formatar, ele passa normal pra tabela, sem erros, porém, quando formato, ele apresenta o erro

Answer (score 1):

Vamos primeiro simplificar o seu código:

```
private void calcularButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String posicao = posicaoTextField.getText();
    String nome = nomeTextField.getText();

    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) valoresTableView.getModel();

    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("R$ ###,###.00");  

    float valor = Float.parseFloat(valorTextField.getText());

    float fator = valor <    3000 ? 0.095f
                : valor <    9000 ? 0.137f
                : valor <   40000 ? 0.163f
                : valor <  100000 ? 0.185f
                : valor <  160000 ? 0.191f
                : valor <  300000 ? 0.217f
                : valor < 1000000 ? 0.223f
                : 0.239f;

    float valorVenda = valor * fator;
    float valorTotalVenda = valor + valorVenda;

    System.out.println(nf.format(valorTotalVenda));
    dtm.addRow(new Object[] {
            nome,
            posicao,
            df.format(valor).toString(),
            df.format(valorTotalVenda).toString(),
            df.format(valorVenda).toString()
    });
}
```

Toda essa sopa de `if`s pode ser reduzida àquele operador ternário encadeado. Observe que por essa abordagem, lacunas que haviam no seu código original, como o 8500 e o 250000, desaparecem. O código resultante é bem menor, mais simples e menos repetitivo. Observe o sufixo `f` nos números não-inteiros.

Também coloquei o código que adiciona uma linha no `dtm` fora disso tudo, para que ele seja sempre executado.

Eliminei também a variável `valorGanho` que sempre produziria o mesmo resultado que `valorVenda`. Para comprovar, veja isso:

```
    float valorTotalVenda = valor + valorVenda;
    float valorGanho = valorTotalVenda - valor;
```

Logo, ao substituir-se o `valorTotalVenda` na segunda equação, temos `valorGanho = valor + valorVenda - valor`, e portanto `valorGanho = valorVenda`.

Comment: Po, valeu, eu tava pensando em fazer isso mais tarde, mas ok kkk, seguinte, funcionou, porém, a formatação ainda apresenta erro, eu acho que é erro do format, tava procurando aqui no google, mas aparentemente não achei nada que pudesse me ajudar.

Comment: Consegui mano, nas configurações da JTable, eu alterei as três ultimas colunas de 'float' para 'object', ai foi kkkk. Desculpa pelo incomodo!! E valeu por toda atenção